# Shouldn't "would be" have been used in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this line in the description of a film on TV:

> *Stu answers a call in a booth and is told that **if he hangs up, he's dead.***

I think it should be "would be dead". Please explain the bold part meaning.

Comment: Please link to your source, or specify it in your question. Your quotation is not a complete sentence, since the **if** clause lacks a subject.

Comment: You're simply mistaken. The auxiliary verb would be appropriate in a ***subjunctive*** context *(If he **were to** hang up, he **would be** dead)*, but not otherwise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comment seems to be helpful.Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain what works and what doesn't. You could switch to past tense, where the natural version would be *Stu **was told** that if he **hung** up, he **would be** dead*. That definitely wouldn't be ***he died*** - some people would use ***he was dead*** there, but most careful speakers would tend to avoid that. They might even claim the simple past was "incorrect" there. But even though ***he will be dead*** is acceptable for your present tense version it's *way* over the top to suggest that simple present is in any way "substandard".

Answer (score 1):

> ...[he] is told that if he hangs up, he will be dead.

This sentence is reported speech: the speaker might actually have said

> "Hang up and you're dead".

In baseball, if you fail to hit the ball three times, you are out: this is stated as

> [Three strikes and you're out](http://blogs.transparent.com/english/three-strikes-and-youre-out/).

**three strikes** is an event: **you're out** is a consequence of that event.

Comparing that with what was probably said to Stu, **hang up** is an event: **you're dead** is a consequence of that event.

The expression "you're dead" in this context is a death threat. The person is telling Stu that if he hangs up the phone, somebody will kill him.

Answer (score -2):

The correct sentence should be:

> Stu answers a call in a booth and is told that if he hangs up, he will be dead.

That is [first conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#First_conditional).

Comment: I don't think this explains why the original sentence was used or why it's wrong, though.  In my opinion, the original sentence uses a kind of reported speech - the person on the other end of the call says "If you hang up, you're dead."

Comment: [*Eat, drink, and be merry, for tomorrow we die.*](http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question110042.html) Are you going to say the correct sentence should be *...tomorrow we **will** die*?